# How to get Google Map zoom level to 23

Tags: javascript, google-maps, zooming

i am creating a webpage for study purpose that has google map that i have implemented using javascript. The problem is i only get a zoom level of 15(that show city level zoom).
How to get a zoom level of 23 on google map(street level zoom) like in most website you can zoom in to show street name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind i got it, change to maptypeId to ROADMAP to get higher zoom